# aterm or gnome-terminal window unresponsive to keyboard events

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, x11, fluxbox

I try to investigate a problem: Depending on the way I launch `aterm` or `gnome-terminal`, the window may or may not be responsive to keyboard events.

The cause of the problem may reside in Aterm, Fluxbox, or Ubuntu 14.04: I'm searching a general linux way to investigate my problem.

In my fluxbox `keys` file I have a line:

```
Mod4 C :Exec aterm
```

This creates a keyboard short-cut for the combination <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> that launches `aterm`.

**Problem**: the `aterm` windows that is created is (19 times out of 20) unresponsive to keyboard events: I cannot use the command line, no character is input, and also I cannot get contextual menu for the window with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> whereas I can with right click button. As if no XWindow keyboard message could reach this window.

Same problem if I launch `aterm` from a `guake` terminal.

**But** I never have the problem if I launch `aterm` from an `xterm` window.

What is strange:

- There's no problem with xterm. If I launch `xterm` by the keyboard shortcut or by guake: the xterm windows is naturally receiving keyboard events and works just like expected.
- aterm was working perfectly with the system Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 12.10 and Ubuntu 13.10
- the aterm version and the fluxbox version is the same between Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04 (where I have the problem): aterm 1.00.01 and fluxbox 1.3.5

I have no idea how to investigate the problem, where to start ?

- what verbose logs should I check ?
- what app could I use to give me an hint on what goes wrong ?
- how to find if it is an xwindow, fluxbox, aterm, or ubuntu bug/problem ?

(As a side note, I want/would like to keep using aterm, because of its native support for transparency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem :

- creating a excutable script `~/default_terminal.sh` which code is calling `gnome-terminal` for example
- calling this script inside my `.fluxbox/keys` and `.fluxbox/menu` configuration file.

Don't what was wrong in the end. It's ok with this trick.